# how to change current database directory?

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

I need to change my current database directory, I want to change its partition. is there any way to change it without 'DownTime'?
is it possible to change it when the database is online?

My DB is DB2 10.5.9 on LUW
      THANKS.

Comment: You should explain __why__ you think this is necessary

Comment: Because the current DB directory is in the wrong path. @mao

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either use the RESTORE command to restore the database from backup, specifying new path details, or use the db2relocatedb command.

Either way it is definitely an offline operation - this is a fundamental change to a core part of the database.

The most obvious way to make this online (more or less) would be to use HADR replication in an HA setup. You could then take the standby database offline, make the necessary changes, switch HADR roles and then do the other side.